# getting noCopy text bold

Tags: html, css

newbie here.

So I made a topbar showing active button with the text "Základ" (basic) written into it, I also wanted to make it so it can´t be copied so it would look better and so I did. But now when I want to make it bold I can´t!  is not working same for font-weigh: bold;. I use external css file. I don´t want to give up on my dream of having a bold title that can´t be copied and so I ask or your help. Anything appriciated!

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 16px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#posunTlacitka {
    transition: margin-left .4s;
    text-align: center;
}

#posunListy {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
        
    }
}


/*HORNÍ LIŠTA*/
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}


.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav div {
    float: left;
    color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #62d1ff;
    color: black;
}

/*LIŠTA NELZE KOPÍROVAT!*/
#noCopy::before {
    content: 'Základ';
    display: block;
}
```

```html
    <div id="posunListy">
        <div class="topnav">
            <div id="posunTlacitka"><span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span></div>
            <a class="active">
                <h2 id="noCopy"></h2>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is bold already. try with `font-weight:400` and see.

Comment: Doesen´t work. I have already tried many combinations of it

Answer (score 0):

As per one of the above comments, your snippet is already showing that the text is bold.  You can see this distinction when you set the following:

```
#noCopy::before {
    content: 'Základ';
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

...resulting in the below snippet.  If you aren't seeing the difference in your development environment, it could be a browser caching issue.  Either way, you've already got it as bold as Lato will get I'm afraid...

Edit:  **this will 'enhance' the effect, but it is a bit of a workaround**

Essentially, adding `-webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;` to your `#noCopy::before` will add an outline stroke to your text, giving the impression of a thicker weight

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 16px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#posunTlacitka {
    transition: margin-left .4s;
    text-align: center;
}

#posunListy {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
        
    }
}


/*HORNÍ LIŠTA*/
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}


.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav div {
    float: left;
    color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #62d1ff;
    color: black;
}

/*LIŠTA NELZE KOPÍROVAT!*/
#noCopy::before {
    content: 'Základ';
    display: block;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
}
```

```html
    <div id="posunListy">
        <div class="topnav">
            <div id="posunTlacitka"><span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span></div>
            <a class="active">
                <h2 id="noCopy"></h2>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I see, my question now is can I somehow undo the boldness so I can add like font-weight: 1500 to it?

Comment: @Holsp I'm afraid the limit of `font-weight` is 'bolder' or '900'.  If you want a more pronounced effect, you'll have to choose a typeface that has a stronger bold weight.  I will update for another workaround you can try